# Is std::swap guaranteed to find nonmember swap by ADL?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap

A textbook by Torsten T. Will on C++11 says that since C++11, `std::swap` will use a nonmember `swap` found by ADL if such a nonmember function is defined, thus the pattern

```
using std::swap;
swap (obj1, obj2);
```

can always be replaced by a simple

```
std::swap (obj1, obj2);
```

Unfortunately, I did not find such a statement anywhere else.

What is the truth?

Comment: I doubt it's true, because if that nonmember `swap` is implemented via `std::swap` then there's infinite mutual recursion. Or worse, that `swap` function doesn't swap objects (but instead happens to do something totally unrelated, and just so happens to be named `swap` and takes two mutable references). But that's just my hunch; I have been known to be totally wrong at times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C++14 (or more specifically N4140):

> *Requires*: Type `T` shall be MoveConstructible (Table 20) and MoveAssignable (Table 22).
>   *Effects*: Exchanges values stored in two locations.

There is nothing here about calling non-member `swap`. So no, there are no guarantees that `std::swap` is implemented via non-member `swap`.

It's not entirely clear if an implementation would even be allowed to implement `std::swap` in terms of a user-defined, non-member ADL `swap`.

Comment: I'm not sure a particular implementation could (legally) do this. It assumes the non-member `swap` produces the desired effect (exchanging values of two objects). If the compiler could see the non-member `swap` implementation and if it was simple enough for the compiler to deduce that it does indeed swap objects, then I suppose it could call it. But I don't think the compiler can make any assumptions about non-trivial non-member `swap` functions, because it would not be clear if they really swapped the objects.

Comment: Ok, then the textbook is wrong here. Generally, however, it's very good.

Comment: @Cornstalks: That's a good point.